# How to upgrade association methods from Sequelize 3.x to 4.x?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am just upgrading from Sequelize 3.x to 4.x, and am trying to restrain myself from tearing out all the hair on my head in frustration.

Here it goes:
In version 3 and below, when associating models we'd create module files which would look somewhat like this:

[file `[project root]/models/user.js`]

```
module.exports = function ( db, Sequelize ) {
    let User = db.define ( 'user', {
        user_id: {
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED
        },
        company_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false
        },
        created_at: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function ( models ) {
                User.hasOne ( models.company, { as: 'company', foreignKey: 'company_id' });
            }
        }
    });
    return User;
};
```

Now for the "upgrade" to version 4 (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html) `classMethods` has been removed, leaving me with no way to reference outside models!

Has anyone been able to figure out how to properly build and maintain associations in Sequelize v4.x?

---

NOTE: I have tried adding the specified method from their docs, but it does not work:

```
// model declaration code...
User.associate = function ( models ) {
    User.hasOne ( models.company, ... );
};
```

---

Additional note: Yes, all my dependencies are installed and working properly. My [file `[project root]/models/index.js`] is properly pulling in all my models. It is only the associations/foreign keys which are not being created.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you say it does not work, however using v4+ the following does work

```
// Class Method
Model.associate = function (models) {
    ...associate the models
};
```

EDIT: To prove, I followed your code exactly. Presuming you are using mysql

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('uzer', {
    user_id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED
    },
    company_id: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED
    },
    created_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    }
  });

  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.hasOne(models.company, {
      foreignKey: 'company_id',
      as: 'company',
    });
  };

  return User;
};
```

You didnt provide the company model, but I assume it is something like

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Company = sequelize.define('company', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  });

  return Company;
};
```

This generates the SQL

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `uzers` (`user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment , `company_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `company_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `uzers` (`user_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Which then gives the database tables

[See database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWXDd.png)

And listing references

[See database reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veKuU.png)

Comment: Not sure how repeating what clearly does not work is supposed to help.

Comment: Unless `Model` is supposed to point to a variable other than the `User` variable declared in the question code.
Please be clear in your answer. Thank you.

Comment: That is a bit rude, as I am trying to help. However I have updated my answer to prove. I am also a contributor to sequelize, so if you find a bug let me know

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude. I set up a new models folder pointing to the existing configuration and it works now as well. Was probably some old code that the new upgrade didn't like, so it looks like I will need to rewrite all of the project models from scratch.

I do want to say thank you for answering. However, perhaps instead of copy/pasting the official documentation which was linked in the question, instead try and offer your thoughts on why something may not work in regard the specified question.
Regardless, thank you very much for taking the time to respond!